# Text editor with autocomplete for C/C++ and userdefined libraries

Tags: editor, syntax-highlighting, code-completion

I am searching now for a while for a replacement for *Qt-Creater* for non Qt programming work. Unfortunatly I really got used to the great auto-complete function of it, which I so far did not find in any other leightweight open source editor. (Qt-Creater does not only enable auto-completion of keywords, but shows all possible functions, member vars, defines, ... in a key-up key-down selectable menulist)

So far I tried Editra, Redcar, gedit, scribes, codelite, geany, SciTE. Most of them just got a very simple version of code completion, which won't show me the arguments of a function, but just put the rest of the word into it (most of the time the first match of a list of possible items cvm::r* could be cvm::rmatrix but also cvm::rvector).
I am neither the emacs nor vim "patriot".
Eclipse would fit, except for it being a total overkill (for me, at least atm).

**So my question: Is there a text editor which supports Code-highlighting and code-completion (in a smart manner)?**
(Preferably under GPLv2/GPLv3/LGPL/MIT/...)

Edit: target is Linux (exclusivly)

regards

Answer (score 1):

Use Notepad++, http://notepad-plus-plus.org/ 
free!!
It can understand and highlight all languages, MATLAB, Python, C++, C, etc... choose your language from the "Language" pulldown menu. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could give [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) a try.
It's cross-platform an has lots of [Extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/VSCode) available. 
Maybe there are sufficient ones for your needs.

Comment: Do not advise people to play with knives when you know that they can accidentally hurt themselves with what you've taught. After wasting my precious time for 3 days to find out which plugin works without conflicting with each other, I've been rewarded, VS Code almost formatted my hard drive.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235338/vs-code-delete-my-unity-project-os-xgit-clean-all
shorturl.at/cpGJ7
shorturl.at/enyzQ
Hope this helps!
I recommend sticking to Vim with vim-clang.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/).  It does highlighting and code completion.  On the download page choose "Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers."

Comment: I did that once, and when I did that, I knew I would never do it again. I need no fully fledged IDE just a simple editor with some extras.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer Visual Studio to Eclipse/CDT for C++ work. C++ is an impossible language to parse and I feel VC++ does a better job than any other editor.