# VS code Delete my Unity project (OS X)(git clean all)

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio-code, recovery

I don't use git but Visual Studio Code has a git icon. So I clicked 'clean all' then my unity project has been deleted.

How can I get my project back?

I'm using OS X.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't get it back using git or Visual Studio Code. May be OSX can help you to restore the files (for example via Time Machine).

**Short explanation of what you have done:**

- You opened a folder (which was **not** a git repository).
- You clicked on the git icon in the menu bar on the left side
- As the opened directory wasn't a git repository there was only the option "Init git repository" that you clicked on.
- A list of files appeared and they were all `unstaged` (that means they weren't already part of the source control)
- You clicked in the menu on `Clean all`.
- A message box appeared displaying the text:

  ```
  Are you sure you want to clean all changes?

  This action is irreversible!

  There are unstaged changes in X files.
  ```
- You submitted the message box by hitting "**Clean Changes**". That deleted all the files in the folder.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I was able to restore via time machine - otherwise it deleted every file off of my macbook. I'll admit i'm a noob, but having that git icon with a 5,000 notification