# Visual Studio Code deleted working directory

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio Code, Version 1.20.1, on Windows Server 2012 R2

[image]

Already **TWO** times I lost **ALL** my files from working directory

In backup folder from %appdata%\Roaming\Code\Backups **nothing**

I scan my partition with File Scavenger, first time I found the folder with files but every content was encoded and I could not restore anything, the second time no folder found

Does someone has encountered such problems?

Comment: Does it happen randomly or after a particular operation?

Comment: @FrancescoB. unique association between working directory names, these folders name were exist before, they was removed and create new ones with the same names

Comment: I understand but does it happen every time you commit to your source control, every time you build...? Does it happen for every project?

Comment: @FrancescoB. randomly, a simple folder from disc 'C', without any build, source control, just a simple folder with html and js files, last edit file was a js file, in opened visual studio code, I found just a message something about opened file no longer exists

Comment: Have you already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33235338/vs-code-delete-my-unity-project-os-xgit-clean-all)? Maybe [this](http://archive.is/EZX1O) too?

Comment: @FrancescoB. thanks for info, but is not related with my problem, in the first link is mac os, and in the second is related to some activities, I did not do anything

Comment: Actually yes, it was on mac os but it doesn't matter I guess; the main point is the current git configuration and possibly staged files. But I guess you didn't do anything related to git before shutting down VS code last time, right?

Comment: @FrancescoB.  related to git no, just click on install button (to install git) after visual studio code first time opened